# Parse.com services, create new app from code

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm asking if it's possible to create new app from my custom code in parse.com account.

Each time i want to setup a new app for a new service, i need to login and manually create the app and then get all the keys.

After that, i'm able to use parse sdk (mainly php) to perform some action inside the parse project (parse app).

I've the need to automate the process of creating new app and get all the keys.

I googled a lot and searched in parse.com docs but without find nothig.

So, it's possible? If yes, how?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a question [that can be addressed/answered by Parse support staff](https://www.parse.com/help). The way your question is phrased (without a clear problem statement with code examples), you will find [better support on the Google Group forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/parse-developers).

Comment: Hi sjagr, i've posted here because, on parse's help page they indicated the possibility to post on stackoverflow adding parse.com  tag. So i've supposed that someone of the parse's team, keep watching the parse.com tagged questions.
And secondly because i love this community :-)
I'l follow your suggestion, however with the hope that someone can halp me here.
In addiction, i've not added any code, because i dont know how and if it possible. That was the point i'd need to be helped.
Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for the kind words - unfortunately SO requires a certain format for asking that has a clear problem statement. However to answer your question, generally if it's not in the documentation, it's not supported functionality. You will have to contact Parse directly to ask them for this API feature (and it's up to them to decide if they'll give it to you.) If I were Parse, I would wonder why you'd even need to do something like that (an app shouldn't be able to create other apps since you're already in an app context...) Also, I've barely seen Parse staff on SO.

Comment: The reasons can be billions, in my case it's a requirement of my customer. He offer different kind of services. In particular conditions we have the need to generate a new app for separating the various contest, statistic, etc. mantaining untoched the performance. Did you know or can suggest any other way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you should consider a different way to "separate" the content. If you want to create a new app for each customer, this is likely going to turn into a feature request (and community developers can't do anything about making a new feature for you.)

Comment: For new feature, what you mean? That parse.com should implement this feature, or that it's possible but the implementation is obviosly reserved to me?

Comment: That Parse.com should implement the API for this feature. It's currently not possible if it's not documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked on parse developer google group and this is the answer:

"We do not currently plan to provide APIs that would allow automatic provisioning of apps in this manner. I'm sorry I don't have a better answer, but you would need to manually create each app."

Link: [click here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/2Gwsyx1DBbA)